# Creating a sub-set of data having only null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data as under in a pandas dataframe [Original shape of the data : 149347 rows and 2 columns]. Purpose includes a text/strings and employeeID includes floats.

[image]

Purpose : Text,Text,Text, ,Text,Text, , ,Text |
Employee : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

I want to create a subset of the data, having only blanks "purpose" and also include relevant employee ID's against such blanks as shown under.

[image]

Code used to achieve the above

```
null_Values = sample['Purpose'].isnull()
# Employee IDs against null values
null_Values['Employee ID'].value_counts()
```

I understand the error in the above code, however unable to achieve the purpose mentioned.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the sample data in text form (so we can copy-paste it)? Also, the blanks are empty strings (`""`)? Or `NaN`s?

Comment: Blanks are empty strings. (Blank row as shown in the pic and no entries in the same)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
print(df[df.Purpose.eq("")])
```

Prints:

```
  Purpose  Employee
2                 3
4                 5
```

---

`df` used:

```
  Purpose  Employee
0    Text         1
1    Text         2
2                 3
3    Text         4
4                 5
```

Comment: I tried the above, Im getting empty dataframe, however I tried the below code ```null_Entries = sample[sample['Purpose'].isnull()]
print(null_Entries)```

Comment: @Sid From the doctext of `.isnull()`: "Characters such as empty
strings `''` or `numpy.inf` are not considered NA values"

Answer (score 0):

df :

```
  Purpose  Employee
0    Text         1
1    Text         2
2                 3
3    Text         4
4                 5
```

Answer:

```
print(df[df.Purpose.isna()])
```